# Install packages in a certain order with Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

Is there a way to set the .toml file up so you will have the dependencies installed in a certain order with Poetry?

Imagine I have the following .toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
wxPython = "4.1.1"
python = "^3.9"
pandas = "^1.4.2"
Faker = "^13.13.0"
pymarc = "^4.2.0"
```

How can I make sure wxPython always is installed first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell Poetry to install packages in a certain order. The reason for this is, because it is not needed.

If the package provide a `wheel` the content is just extracted to the appropriate target folder.

If the package only provides an `sdist` and therefor a `wheel` needs to be build, this happens an a fresh isolated environment. Thus, the build process does not have access to any previously installed package.

If the build process fail, due to a missing dependency in the build environment, the package maintainers miss to declare those build-dependencies according to [PEP-518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/). Once this is fixed, those dependencies are installed in the isolated build environment during the build process.

Comment: Is there no tactical way for me to fix this? I am asking because for example dm-tree needs cmake - but does not define it as a dep. It does not seem reasonable for me to fix dm-tree to get my project up and running..

Comment: @DionysiosGeorgiadis: No, there's nothing Poetry can do here. File an issue at dm-tree. The fix is easy to do on their side.

Comment: Actually, I tried using a separate group for that one package that I install after the rest of my deps. I feel like this should work in theory?

Answer (score 0):

Poetry already takes care of this for you. It will install `wxPython` in your example before any other packages that declare a dependency on it.

Comment: Do you need any specific syntax? I cannot make that happen with poetry install or poetry update

Comment: @Fontanka16 Why is this a problem? Are you getting any errors? If so, you should google them or ask about how to solve them specifically.

Comment: In the above example, wx python gets installed last every time.

Comment: @Fontanka16 You still haven't explained why that's a problem

Comment: There seem to be some kind of circular dependency where installing wxpython fails if it is installed last.

Comment: Installing it first works

Comment: @Fontanka16 What error do you get when it fails? Please edit your original question to show this.

Comment: @Fontanka16 But to answer your question directly. I am not aware of any syntax to force poetry to install packages in a certain order. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), so my questions are to get some information about the original problem to see if there might be another solution than the one you are asking about here.