# Can I get Poetry to reinstall ipykernel after installing ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, python-poetry

I’m developing a Python package.  I used Poetry to set up my development environment; I intend to distribute my code through PyPI.  One of my dependencies requires ipywidgets<7.7.2, as documented [here](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/3274).  Due to a bug (mentioned [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2257#issuecomment-1110226272)), ipykernel must be reinstalled after ipywidgets is installed.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73783532) says that developers can’t specify the order that Poetry installs packages.  Is this still true?  If so, what is the simplest way to get users to re-install ipykernel after installing ipywidgets?

I could add something to my documentation telling users to run `pip uninstall ipykernel` then `pip install ipykernel`.  But this seems like it would trip up unwary users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming you have activated Poetry virtual environment with `poetry shell` command
- When you run `pip install` after `poetry install`, it unconditionally  overwrites any packages installed the virtual environment

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Running `pip install` after `poetry install` allows me to run the code on my computer.  I'm nervous about distribution though.  AFAIK Poetry can prepare a package for PyPI distribution, so that the user can install my code using `pip install <library_name>`.  I don't want to make all users run a separate `pip install ipykernel` after installing my code.  But if there's no alternative, I can do that.

Comment: You cannot fix the distribution channel. All you can do is that until the upstream is fixed you document this issue. Or alternative pin down everything to older versions that is a known good version set.

Comment: I was afraid of that... thanks for confirming it though.  I think this solution will be acceptable for my use case.